# Easiest ways to get Legendaries in Borderlands Pre Sequel

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Does anyone know of any way to get Legendary weapons quickly end efficiently in Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel? I've tried grinding basic enemies and npcs, but haven't seemed to be able to get any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legendaries appear in the vendor at a much higher rate than BL2 - I got three at Level 15 alone. Legendary drops from random enemies are probably as low as they were in BL2...like way low. IF you know what boss drops the one you are looking for AND that boss respawns (many in the TPS do not), then you can farm him/her/it. I wouldn't waste money trying for getting a legendary from the slots -- again, very low odds it they are same as BL2 -- use that money to buy one from a vendor when it appears. It will.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no legendaries, you can try farming Iwajira.  He has a relatively high drop rate for a legendary rocket launcher which you can use in the grinder. Just remember to always use moonstones when you grind them, or you may get a purple gun back.

Comment: I may have to do that once I decide to play True Vault Hunter mode. I beat the game a couple weeks ago. I got some legendaries from a glitch but, I would rather earn them legit.

Answer (score 1):

To get a legendary out of the grinder , you need too Grind 2 legendaires and a purple . The purple will dictate what gun you get ! If you want a pistol do a pistol & if you have no legendaries then check the stores !

Comment: That I understand and know how to do, but I meant like, what is the easiest way to get them if you have none? Would it be just farming them? Or trying my luck at the slot machine?

Answer (score -1):

Kill Bosun for Cryophobia rocket launcher,
Kill Felicity for Quasar grenade,
Kill even-more-disgusting-tork for flakker shotgun,
Kill Sentinel for The ZX-1 laser,
Kill Iwajira for Thingy rocket launcher,
Kill RedBelly for striker shotgun,
Or check shop for legendaries.